# Why does locking the computer (by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Delete) take so long?

Tags: windows-7, performance, lock-screen

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to lock my Windows 7 computer, it takes a long time before the lock screen is displayed.

Why would it be so slow to load the lock screen and how can I fix it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think it's written in my post ;)

Comment: Are you talking about a specific computer, or do you think it's slow in general (on every Windows 7 machine)? Mine is fast, and so has been every computer I can think of that isn't busy doing something.  Perhaps you have a busy (background) process?  What have you tried already to diagnose?

Comment: *> I think it's written in my post*   No, actually it’s not. What exactly is *“loading”*, Task Manager, the Windows logon prompt?

Comment: I have seen it the machine is ground to a halt, so you press ctrl-alt-del to get up task-manager to kill off the offending process. But it takes an age. I thing it used to run an higher priority, so you could use it to kill stuff.

Comment: @Synetech it's easy to understand what I meant by saying "loading". And you can understand, if you want ;)

Comment: @SEARAS, I am usually pretty good at understanding questions that are not clear and most people can’t figure out, but no it is absolutely **not** clear what you mean by “loading”. **What** is loading? Windows? The Task Manager? The desktop? Don’t take an attitude because it’s not just me who is having difficulty understanding what you are asking; just look at the comments and the fact that your question was closed. *Nobody* knows what you are asking. I don’t understand why instead of simply clarifying your question you are getting passive-aggressive and attacking our comprehension abilities.

Comment: @Synetech, only one thing loads in Win7, when you press Ctrl+Alt+Del!

Comment: *> only one thing loads in Win7, when you press Ctrl+Alt+Del!*   @SEARAS, nope that’s not even remotely correct, by a long shot whatsoever at all, by any stretch of the imagination. I already listed no less than four different things that can be loaded/displayed either directly or indirectly when pressing it.

Comment: @Synetech, don't fight ;) LogonUI (by default) starts one of its screens  , when you press it. OK ?)

Comment: @SEARAS, I’m not fighting. Why couldn’t you just say you meant the logon screen at the start instead of being obtuse. Like I said, pressing `C+A+Del` also loads the lock-screen, the Task Manager, and so on. In fact, your statement about the logon screen isn’t true; the logon screen is *not* shown by default if you are not connected to a domain. For example, a person who is using Windows Home on their laptop might have no idea what you are talking about, so being specific helps get your questions answered rather than assuming everybody is using the same system and setup as you (or is psychic).

Comment: Does it happen only when [logging in for the first](http://www.elmajdal.net/win7/Joining_Windows_7_To_A_Domain/9-press-ctrl-alt-del.png) time after booting or every time (e.g., after you have already logged in and want to [lock the system](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-QtU1xrsU6T0/TmH_GiqJM6I/AAAAAAAAAi8/5Vtq3_m2fKw/s1600/ctrl-alt-del_43893.jpg))?

Comment: @Synetech , it happens when my RAM is >80% filled. I think user88311 is true, it's hardware problem, not software.

Comment: *> it happens when my RAM is >80% filled.*   That’s not what I asked, but since your RAM could not be 80% full on boot, you must be talking about locking the system—which is the complete opposite of what you were indicating with your previous statements which sounded more like you were talking about the logon screen. (Sheesh, so much work just extract such a simple piece of information.)

Comment: If it only happens when the RAM is full like you said, then what is probably happening is that when you press `Ctrl+Alt+Del` to lock the system, Windows pages out a bunch of stuff to disk (which of course is slow). Watch the HD LED to see evidence of this. In this case, you can get more RAM, reduce your memory usage, limit your virtual memory (not going to be much help overall), get faster drive, get an SSD, or just wait for it.

Comment: @Synetech - Actually, I suspect that very often when the disk is busy like that it's not pageout but rather some sort of NTFS housekeeping activity.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, that’s possible (it could also be defragging), but I would think unless it was manually done (which seems unlikely in this case), that it would not be—automatically—doing those sorts of things until *after* the system is locked and becomes idle.

Comment: @Synetech - Well, something is weird about it.  A normal POT would be set to run at low priority, and unless free pages were simply not available, would not prevent other stuff from working like this phenomenon does.  (Keep in mind that only CHANGED pages need to be paged out before being stolen, and the vast majority of pages referenced in the system are not changed.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks, in my experience, any time the system is made idle, Windows tends to page stuff out regardless of how full the memory is or is not. There are at least two questions here where people are asking about why their system is sluggish after idling for a long time. Perhaps Windows is doing the same thing on locking, but a little too quickly.

Comment: @Synetech -- If the system is "idle" there are no "dirty" pages that need paging out.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, the whole system doesn’t have to be idle; if a program is idle for a while and happens to use a lot of memory, it is likely to to get paged out. Obviously it’s more likely if memory is low, but seemingly even when there’s still plenty of free memory.

Comment: @Synetech -- But "paging out" doesn't remove pages from memory, it just turns off the "dirty" bit.

Comment: @DanielRHicks ??? You know how the disk thrashes sometimes because of memory? *That* happens when you try to use a program that has been idle for a while.

Comment: @Synetech -- Windows thrashes for no reason at all -- no evidence that it due to "memory".

Comment: @DanielRHicks, are you talking about your own issue or the OP’s? If you have an issue of your own, you should start your own question (this one is closed anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same problem exists in vista and xp, and still in 8 as well. The problem as well as the solution is in the hardware. Usually the hardware that comes in a computer is bare minimum to run the software, I noticed the same problem in one of my own computers but after adding a gig of ram to the computer it became instantaneous.

EDIT: So simply put, add a extra gig of ram to your computer and it should solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

Try and use other shortcuts to do the same functions as some of the options on the Ctrl-Alt-Delete screen.

- Ctrl-Alt-Escape  Brings up the Windows Task Manager
- WindowsKey-L  Locks the computer

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-Del doesn't bring up the UAC prompt.

Comment: Your correct, Ctrl-Alt-Delete doesn't fade the screen so removed that part of the answer.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Escape brings task manager, not Ctrl+Alt+Escape